# Error invoking clientX with Dart2JS

Tags: dart, dart2js

When compiling code with dart dart2js, and run in chrome or firefox

```
void main() {
  window.onMouseDown.listen((e) => print(e.clientX));
}
```

Result:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

In Dartium there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.client.x` should work.
`e.clientX` was available for a long time but deprecated. Maybe it was removed recently.